# Verify USB devices are connected to particular USB Ports

Tags: vbscript, cmd

I'm trying to run the below Visual Basic Script, which is executed via CMD. The script works great, however it only covers a very basic purpose. I'm trying to verify that USB1 port has a particular device connected to it, either by checking the device name, or VID/PID. Could someone help me with a script that could verify certain USB ports have particular devices connected?

The environment is identical on the multiple machines this will be ran on, and for example, I want to verify that USB Port 1 contains a device with "Scanner" in its name, or by checking the ID of the device. Is this possible?

```
Option Explicit
Dim oWMISrv, collDvcs, collUSBDvcs, iUSBDvc , iDvc, sDvcID, sPID, sVID

Function ReplaceX(ByVal sValue, ByVal sPattern, ByVal sNValue)
    Dim oReg : Set oReg = New RegExp
    oReg.Pattern = sPattern
    ReplaceX = oReg.Replace(sValue, sNValue)
    Set oReg = Nothing
End Function

Set oWMISrv = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set collDvcs = oWMISrv.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_USBControllerDevice")

For Each iDvc In collDvcs
    If InStr(iDvc.Dependent, "VID_") Then ' Except keychain drives

        sDvcID = ReplaceX(iDvc.Dependent, ".*""(.*)""", "$1")
        sPID = ReplaceX(sDvcID, ".*PID_([^\\]*).*", "$1")
        sVID = ReplaceX(sDvcID, ".*VID_([^&]*).*", "$1")

        Set collUSBDvcs = oWMISrv.ExecQuery _
        ("Select * From Win32_PnPEntity Where DeviceID = '" & sDvcID & "'")
        For Each iUSBDvc in collUSBDvcs
            Wscript.Echo "Name : "& iUSBDvc.Description
            Wscript.Echo "VID : "& sVID
            Wscript.Echo "PID : "& sPID
            Wscript.Echo String(50, "-")
        Next
        Set collUSBDvcs = Nothing

    End If
Next

Set collDvcs = Nothing
Set oWMISrv = Nothing
```

Comment: How are you determining "USB Port 1" from this output?

Comment: That's what I'm struggling with, I'm looking to see if perhaps a .vbs script could check particular rear USB ports for the devices.

Comment: It sounds like you want information about what is connected to a specific port on a specific machine. If so, perhaps the machine maker (Dell, HP, etc.) would be a source of information. What if someone plugs 4-port USB hub in? I am not sure that WMI or CIM are going to report anything about which "port" a device is plugged into.

Comment: The device uses 6 COM Ports, so i'm looking into exactly which devices are using the COM Ports, to see if there's a way to check if the device is connected to the correct COM Port.